# Идентификация типа в шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, vector, шаблоны-с++

Не могу понять каким образом в данном случае происходит идентификация типа. Вроде передаю объект `std::vector<float>`, а в функции оказывается `float`. VS 12

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned int uint;

template <typename T>
void InsertionSort(std::vector<T> &_vec) // Сортировка вставками
{
  std::cout << typeid(_vec).name() << std::endl; // Проверка типа

  for(uint i = 1; i < _vec.size(); i++)
  {
    T key = _vec[i];

    uint j = i - 1;

    while(key < _vec[j] && j > 0)
    {
      _vec[j + 1] = _vec[j];
      --j;
    }

    _vec[j] = key;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<float> vec;

  vec.push_back(34.54f);
  vec.push_back(34.53f);
  vec.push_back(0.0f);
  vec.push_back(5.6f);

  InsertionSort(vec);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что означает "а в функции оказывается float"? Что именно "оказывается float"?

Comment: Видимо имеется в виду что `std::cout << typeid(_vec).name() << std::endl;` выводит `float`. Если это так, то интересно что за компилятор используется, потому как VC2012 пишет правильно: `std::vector<float>`

Comment: InsertionSort плохое имя для функции. согласно конвенции следует писать insertionSort. Только имена классов могут начинаться с большой буквы

Comment: @AndreyChernukha, конвенции у всех разные.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha, отвечайте по существу, или проходите мимо.

Comment: @Cerbo, пишу в вижуал студии 12.

Comment: @neitron, уточните вопрос. Не понятно, чего Вы хотите. Распишите то, что Вы ожидаете, и что получаете. Иначе на Ваш вопрос ответить нереально.

Comment: @neitron: Ещё раз, почему именно вы считаете, что в функцию `InsertionSort` приходит `float`?

Comment: @VladD, @ixSci, прощу прощения за неясность. потому, что проверяю тип `std::cout << typeid(T).name();`, и получаю `float`. но я предпологал, что получу `std::vector<std::vector<float>>&`, вопрос  - почему передавая `std::vector<float>`, я получаю `float`? (вижуал студия 2012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> я предпологал, что получу `std::vector<std::vector<float>>&`

Это не так.

Когда вы объявляете функцию как

```
template <typename T>
void InsertionSort(std::vector<T> &_vec)
```

— это значит, что тип вашего `_vec` будет `std::vector<T> &` для *некоторого* `T`. Теперь, когда вы передаёте в функцию `vec` типа `std::vector<float> &`, то компилятор смотрит, можно ли сопоставить тип аргумента (то, что вы реально передаёте) и тип параметра (то, что от вас ожидается).

Поскольку ожидается `std::vector<T> &` для некоторого `T`, а реально приходит `std::vector<float> &`, компилятор радостно заключает: «ага, подходит для `T = float`», и компилирует ваш шаблон с таким значением `T`.

Если бы вы передали в функцию `std::vector<std::vector<float>>&`, компилятор бы увидел, что тип подходит для `T = std::vector<float>` (но это не наш случай).

Если бы вы передали в функцию просто `float`-переменную, то компилятор бы подумал «не могу придумать, для какого `T` у нас `float = vector<T>`», и не стал бы компилировать вашу функцию.

---

Заметьте, что вы можете сами точно контролировать, как именно будет раскрыто `T`, путём явного указания аргумента шаблона:

```
InsertionSort< std::vector<float> >(vec);
```

Это не скомпилируется, потому что для `T = std::vector<float>` тип аргумента должен быть `std::vector<T>& == std::vector< std::vector<float> > &`, а у вас передаётся просто `std::vector<float> &`. Но по крайней мере вы будете контролировать результат.

Comment: @neitron: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> template <typename T>
> void InsertionSort(std::vector<T> &_vec) // Сортировка вставками
> ```
>
> Вроде передаю объект std::vector

Сравниваем:

```
std::vector < T     > &   // объявление
std::vector < float > &   // передаёшь
```

Что здесь `T`? Очевидно, `float`.

Comment: @Qwerty, да, но я предпологал, что получу `std::vector<std::vector<float>>&`. Разве, исхода из сравнений определяется тип, думал, что тип определяется динамически для переданого аргумента (а передается, как вы подметили, `std::vector<float>`). Поєтому и задал вопрос, так как запутался.

Comment: @neitron, a я что сравнил? Это и есть тип переданного аргумента.

Comment: @neitron, "тип определяется динамически", всё, что связано с шаблонами определяется во время компиляции. Никакой работы во время исполнения, а значит никакой динамики. Шаблоны в C++ очень далеки от generics в C#